# Maximum probability of a set of vectors from $ \mathbb{F}_2^n $ being linearly independent

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, finite-fields, linear-independence

Suppose $ m $ vectors from the vector space $ \mathbb{F}_2^n $ are selected independently according to a distribution $ P $ over $ \mathbb{F}_2^n $. Here $ \mathbb{F}_2 $ denotes the field with two elements. My question is this: for which $ P $ is the probability of them being linearly independent maximized? EDIT as a clarification: Equivalently, an $ m\times n $ matrix is formed by sampling the rows independently from a distribution $ P $ over $ \mathbb{F}_2^n $. For which $ P $ is the probability of the matrix being full-rank maximized?

It seems obvious that, for any $ m \in \{2, \ldots,n\} $, the maximum is attained when $ P $ is uniform over all the non-zero vectors ($ \mathbb{F}_2^n \setminus \{0\} $). This is indeed true when $ m = 2 $, which can be concluded based on concavity arguments, but the general case seems less trivial. Does anyone have an idea how this could be (dis)proved?

Comment: I know it's an obvious and silly question, but:  obviously the 'best' $P$ will assign $0$ weight to $0$.  (Otherwise, just re-assign that weight to any non-$0$ vector to increase the "linear independence probability".)  Suppose that it assigns different weights $p$ and $q$ to two non-$0$ vectors $v$ and $w$.  Can it ever happen that the distribution that assigns the average weight $(p + q)/2$ to both $v$ and $w$, and is otherwise unchanged, has a lower "linear independence probability"?

Comment: Also, just to be clear, if a vector is ever selected twice, you count that as a failure, right?  (That is, you are really looking at the indexed family of selections, not just the set of selected vectors?)

Comment: @LSpice To your first question - I don't know :) To your second question - yes, selecting some vector twice would mean that the condition of linear independence is violated. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Do not have an answer for fixed n, but there is asymptotic sense in which the distribution doesn't matter unless it is very localized, see 1) Kahn J. and Komlós J. (2001), Singularity Probabilities for Random Matrices over Finite Fields, Combinatorics, Probability and Computing, 10(2), 137-157 and 2) Vinh L. A. (2012), Singular matrices with restricted rows in vector spaces over finite fields, Discrete Mathematics, 312(2), 413-418.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky Thanks for the references, I wasn't aware of the second one.